# Joomla 3: custom module style with chrome

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-template

I'm trying to set custom style for Joomla module. I have created file modules.php in /templates/MY_TEMPLATE_NAME/html directory. Content of this file below:

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

function modChrome_custom($module, &$params, &$attribs)
{
     echo '<h3>test style chrome</h3>';
}
```

Now, I try to output module from my template with this style. I do it this way:

```
 <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-1" style="custom"  />
```

But it looks like my custom style is not applying to the module and all I see is a standard module layout. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

you need to go to Extensions->Module manager,
select the module that you want to apply your custom style,
in the Advanced tab there is an option "Module Style", under your template name there should be 'custom'
select that as the style